# How to pick the value numbers from another sheet using google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 google sheet tabs, first sheet1 have col A - Email address, Col B - message, Col C - status.
and second sheet2 have only one column Col A - voucher code, I have insert all my necessary numbers in sheet2 Col A. So each time I run my script will send email out and automatically pick the numbers from sheet2 base on the last row of sheet1 data. Email sent without issue, but I fail to get voucher code data from sheet2 Col A in my email.

[image: Picture]

```
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

function sendEmails2() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var strRow2 = 2;
var numRows2 = 2;
var dataRange2 = sheet2.getRange(strRow2, 1, numRows2, 1)
 
var data2 = dataRange2.getValue();
  
for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; ++j) {    
var row2 = data2[j];
var code = row2[0];
} 
  
var startRow = 2; 
var numRows = 2; 

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);

var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0]; 
var message = row[1] + "\n" + code // this code no working 
var emailSent = row[2]; 
if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) 
var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT); 
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
}
}
```

Comment: This code does not work and it is very bad formatted. Can you show us a minimal reproducible example? Also which voucher number do you need ? there is no matching key between Sheet1 and Sheet2. Please improve the question so the community will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on google app script and new for this posting, i try my best to improve my question. i amend my screenshot, hopefully your guy will understand what i need, thank you.

Comment: Daniel, see my posted answer. I assumed that the subject of the email will be the message (COL B, sheet1) and the message will be the voucher. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion solution, really appreciated, yes this is what i want, sorry for make you confusing. email subject i did put in the google sheet, message is email body and how to use htmlbody instead of body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the last row that has content you should use: [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow).

Here is the solution:

```
function sendEmail() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';
  
  var sh1_LR = sh1.getLastRow();

  var sh1_EA = sh1.getRange(sh1_LR,1).getValue();
  var sh1_M = sh1.getRange(sh1_LR,2).getValue();
  var sh2_V = sh2.getRange(sh1_LR,1).getValue();
 
  try{
  MailApp.sendEmail(sh1_EA, sh1_M, sh2_V);
  sh1.getRange(sh1_LR,3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
  }
  catch(e)
  {Logger.log("sendEmail failed")}     
}
```